# How to Eliminate Duplicates Within Same Cell with Separator

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Say I have one column that contains cells:
Apple||Banana
Banana|Apple
Apple||Apple
Banana|Banana
Apple||Banana||Apple
etc...

How do I eliminate any instance of a word appearing twice (separated by a double pipe) within a single cell, but retain multiple appearances of the same word within the column?

I would also be happy to hear a solution that exists in OpenRefine if that makes it easier. Whatever works. Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with your mock data. Describing spreadsheets with words can be confusing and it's much better to just see the data itself. If you don't want to share a file of yours, that's fine, you can just use [this link that will create new blank Google Sheet for you.](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform)

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @DavidTan Sure, here is a link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17TInR9AzmXpY7hehAOUYYlsx7vuRma7XRjk4Y6YzewI/edit#gid=0

Comment: If the answer does not match your desired results, please show your _manually entered_ desired results in the sample spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce()` and `regexreplace()`, like this:

```
=let( 
  data, A2:A, 
  words, unique(flatten(split(join(" ", data), " |", true, true))), 
  regexes, map(words, lambda(word, "\b" & word & "\|\|" & word & "\b")), 
  replaceWith, map(words, lambda(word, "")), 
  byrow( 
    data, 
    lambda( 
      row, 
      if( 
        len(row), 
          trim( 
          reduce( 
            row, sequence(counta(regexes)), 
            lambda( 
              acc, regexIndex, 
              regexreplace( 
                acc, 
                index(regexes, regexIndex), 
                index(replaceWith, regexIndex) 
              ) 
            ) 
          ) 
        ), 
        iferror(1/0)  
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

The formula will find all instances of a *word* followed by `||` followed by the *same word*.

Words are expected to be separated by spaces or one or more pipe characters `|`.

The results look like this:

| Data where some words are separated by a double pipe `||` | Remove instances of `word1` `||` `word1` |
| --- | --- |
| Apple`||`Banana Banana`|`Apple Apple`||`Apple Banana`|`Banana Apple`||`Banana`||`Apple | Apple`||`Banana Banana`|`Apple Banana`|`Banana Apple`||`Banana`||`Apple |
| Dweezil Apple`||`Apple MoonUnit | Dweezil MoonUnit |
| Dweezil Banana`||`Banana MoonUnit | Dweezil MoonUnit |
| Dweezil Apple`||`Apple Banana`||`Banana MoonUnit | Dweezil MoonUnit |
| Apple`||`Apple Dweezil Banana`||`Banana MoonUnit | Dweezil MoonUnit |
| Dweezil Apple`||`Apple MoonUnit Banana`||`Banana | Dweezil MoonUnit |
| Dweezil Apple`|`Apple Banana`||`Banana MoonUnit | Dweezil Apple`|`Apple MoonUnit |
| Dweezil Apple`||`Apple Banana`|`Banana MoonUnit | Dweezil Banana`|`Banana MoonUnit |
| Apple`||`Banana`||`Apple | Apple`||`Banana`||`Apple |
| Apple`||`Banana`||`Banana`||`Apple | Apple`||||`Apple |
| Apple`||`Banana`||`Apple`||`Apple | Apple`||`Banana`||` |

Comment: Edited the answer to replace `unique(transpose(split(data, " |", true, true)))` with `unique(flatten(split(join(" ", data), " |", true, true)))`.